# Software for prioritising issues / tasks in an ordered list/queue (ideally in Github)?

Tags: project-management, agile, github, issue-tracking

It seems to me that the best way to manage priority for programming tasks in a backlog is to simply put them in order. Do the top task first, second one next. If priority changes, re-order the queue. I thought this was exactly how things were supposed to work in Agile.

I have yet to find an online open-source team task manager that supports custom ordering of tasks this way - although I might be out of date. [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home) definitely doesn't. [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) doesn't seem to. When we used [Agilo](http://www.agilofortrac.com) in my previous company, it didn't seem to either. The only service I've found that implements this simple concept well is [Google Tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/), but that's hardly suitable for managing software projects.

I don't understand why this isn't the standard way to manage priority.

My ideal way to track issues would be through [Github](https://github.com/). As far as I can tell [Github Issues](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation) also doesn't support custom ordering of tasks. Does anyone know if there's any way to implement this on top of Github Issues somehow? Is there any way I can suggest it as a feature?

Comment: not github related, but you should check out [trello](http://www.trello.com) too

Comment: It seems like Assembla has updated their product since you last used them. https://www.assembla.com/agile?agilePage=planning

Comment: Have you tried [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/)?  It's designed for agile software development, and it does a great job of handling ordering and reordering tasks.  It's not open source, but it's free for public projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related to github this one might be an interesting solution:
http://huboard.com

Huboard is a solution based on the API of Github. It uses the real GitHub issues as you are familiar with when using GitHub.

It allows you to sort and manage the tasks by dragging them.

Because they are from the API it means all data is the actual GitHub data. So if you commit to close a task it will also be closed in Huboard. That makes it special, it's really the real data without synchronisation issues.

Comment: Wow. That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. This project, and you, my friend, are awesome.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and what it's good for? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: Added some more info about it. Can't explain it better than their homepage but it should work out this way I expect. According to the example it is not equal to a link-only answer btw. It's a direct link to the solution, not to some kind of overview site (our tourist office ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had a similar challenge I wanted to solve just a few minutes ago. I downloaded Task Coach, which is open source and written in Python. It's a very detailed task manager.

http://taskcoach.org/

The reasons I think it might help you is that it supports ordering based on priority, so you can simply list your tasks in order and change the priority which will re-order the list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm glad someone else has had this problem. Unfortunately Taskcoach isn't a great solution for me because I need to manage tasks for my whole team, and allow stakeholders to create new tasks, anyone to add comments etc., so it really has to be an online solution with management.

Comment: @RobinWinslow ? did you find such a tool? I need exactly the same :|

Comment: Yes, huboard, waffle etc. There are now a ton of task board products which will give you a board for managing GitHub issues in a priority order.